# How to select document by string using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select the document element using a string retrieved by a data attribute using jQuery.
I have an element with a data attribute that contains a selector.

HTML:

```
<div class="some-element" data-scroll-target="document"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var $container = $('.some-element');
var scrollTarget = $container.data('scroll-target');
// This will not return the document because `scrollTarget` is a string.
// Equal to $('document')
var $shouldBeDocument = $(scrollTarget);
```

Is there a way to target the document with a String?

Comment: did u try: `document.getElementsByClassName($container).data-scroll-target`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `scrollTarget` text is "document" use the `document` object, if not use the text:

```js
var $container = $('.some-element');
var scrollTarget = $container.data('scroll-target');
// if the text is document, use the document object
var target = scrollTarget === 'document' ? document : scrollTarget; 
var $shouldBeDocument = $(target);

console.log(target);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="some-element" data-scroll-target="document"></div>
```

Comment: Did some more searching and also went through the Sizzle source code but couldn't find any hidden magic selector to achieve what I wanted. This method is probably the most simple way to go. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the document.

```
var scrollTarget = $('.some-element').attr('data-scroll-target');
console.log(scrollTarget);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log($('*[data-scroll-target="document"]').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="some-element" data-scroll-target="document">document</div>

<div class="some-element" data-scroll-target="file">file</div>
```